# Getting same element even element is not there in DOM using Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

Configuration :

> Selenium : 2.53.1
>
> Java : 7
>
> Eclipse IDE : Mars

I'm using POM framework and using PageFactory design pattern for that. I have below Homepage code :

```
public class RCONHomePage 
{
    @FindBy(css =".ng-scope>a span[translate='login.register']")
    public WebElement loginLink;
    
    @FindBy(xpath ="//a//span[text()='DASHBOARD']")
    public List<WebElement> dashboardLink;
    
    @FindBy(name = "number")
    public WebElement globalSearchMobileNumbertextBox;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='btn rc-bg-border']")
    public WebElement globalSearchButton;
    
    @FindBy(css = "p.page-title.ng-scope >span")
    public WebElement globalSearchResult;
    
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public RCONHomePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
    
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 30), this);
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    public void clickOnLoginLink()
    {
        loginLink.click();
    }
    
    public void enterMobileNumberForGlobalSearch(String mobileNumber)   
    {
        globalSearchMobileNumbertextBox.clear();
        globalSearchMobileNumbertextBox.sendKeys(mobileNumber);
    }
    
    public void clickGlobalSearchButton()
    {
        globalSearchButton.click();
    }
    
    public String getGlobalSearchResult()
    {

        System.out.println(globalSearchResult.getText());
        return globalSearchResult.getText();

    }
}
```

My usecase is enter valid and invalid mobile number in global search and verify the result weather that number is exist there or not in [this site](https://www.rcontacts.in/)

Issue is, my test is showing correct result if mobile no is invalid (shows "record not found") but if i enter valid mobile no and verify the text it still shows "record not found". if i manually do find that text for valid number .The element is not available in DOM.

These are test method for the scenarios:

```
@Test
public void searchForNonExistContact() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
        homepage = new RCONHomePage(driver);
    
        homepage.enterMobileNumberForGlobalSearch("9422307800");
        homepage.clickGlobalSearchButton();
        System.out.println(homepage.globalSearchResult.getText());
    }
    
}

@Test
public void searchForExistContact() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
        homepage = new RCONHomePage(driver);
    
        homepage.enterMobileNumberForGlobalSearch("9422307801");
        homepage.clickGlobalSearchButton();
        System.out.println(homepage.globalSearchResult.getText());
    }
    
}
```

As far as I know it should happen if I use `@CacheLookup` for that element. I don't know why this happening. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Did you try reload in test function once ? Your above code looks fine just wondering whether your js is storing the value as part of DOM element or cache is maintained ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the code looks fine, and the issue may looks like "the test fail at run-time but not at debugging time". In my case, I would do some more steps to figure out what should happened:

1. The correct text might be appear "after a delay", or "record not found" is the default message and it takes time to be "record found". In this case, I will implicit wait for some second and run the script again.
2. In stead of print out the text, I would call findEment with the expected text. By doing it, the system will wait until time-out to get the element.

I hope these step could help to figure out the behavior of the system to have better approach for testing the scenario.

In my case, I used following function to wait for the test:

```
 /***
 * An expectation for checking WebElement with given locator has text with a value as a part of it
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param pattern - used as expected text matcher pattern
 * @param timeout
 * @return Boolean true when element has text value containing @value
 */
public boolean textMatches(By locator, Pattern pattern, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textMatches(locator, pattern));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking WebElement with given locator has specific text
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param value - used as expected text
 * @param timeout
 * @return Boolean true when element has text value equal to @value
 */
public boolean textToBe(By locator, String value, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(locator, value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified element.
 * @param element - the WebElement
 * @param text - to be present in the element
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the element contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElement(WebElement element, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the element that matches the given locator.
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param text - to be present in the element found by the locator
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the first element located by locator contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElementLocated(By locator, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(locator, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified elements value attribute.
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param text - to be present in the value attribute of the element found by the locator
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the value attribute of the first element located by locator contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElementValue(By locator, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(locator, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified elements value attribute.
 * @param element - the WebElement
 * @param text - to be present in the element's value attribute
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the element's value attribute contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElementValue(WebElement element, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(element, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

with

```
private Wait<WebDriver> getWebDriverFluentWait(int timeout) {
    return new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Comment: some pause in script is working , but is there any robust solution for that ?

Comment: I have edited the answer with couple functions using fluentwait to wait for the text status. Hope it helps.